# scale images for ldpi mdpi hdpi and xhdpi

Tags: android, scaling

i have 5 buttons with background_button image  size 267x63. I have copied all background_button with resolution 267x63 in ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi.
When i try to run my app, button is big in 2,7" QWGA but in tablet mode is small.

Which is the best risolution for my background_button in ldpi mdpi hdpi and xhdpi?

xml button:

```
    <Button  
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

if i scale background_button and set this:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

my button is strict...
can you help me please?

Comment: read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have read this article but i don't understanding. I have created layouts folrders... but the ultimate problem are the drawable

Comment: This might also help you: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you should not to place THE SAME images to all folders -ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi.

Lets imagine, you want to support xxhdpi devices. You create image for xxhdpi (for example 1Mb) and put it to all folders.
And what will you get on a ldpi device? Image will be scaled. Quality of image on the screen will be horrible.
And another thing: if you want to have 100 images on a screen at the same time, each by 2-5Mb, and you create all of this images for xxhdpi devices, then you can get OutOfMemoryError on ldpi device.

So, the best practice is NOT to put the same images to all the folders.
If you have some resolution independent images, then you can put them into drawable folder (without postfix). But you should NOT put the same images to ldpi and xxhdpi folders.

So answers with resizing are terrible.

Look at this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

At "Alternative drawables" paragraph.
On this image

[image]

you can see that for xhdpi device you should have image 2 times larger than for mdpi.
And so on.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to display according to screen resolution -

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).
                   getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

**Code to resize image ---**

```
private Bitmap resizeImage( final Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap resizedImage = null;
        if(image != null)
        {
        int maxHeight = 80; //actual image height coming from internet
        int maxWidth = 150; //actual image width coming from internet

        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
        if ( imageHeight > maxHeight )
        imageHeight = maxHeight;
        int imageWidth = (imageHeight*image.getWidth()) // image.getHeight();
        if ( imageWidth > maxWidth ) {
        imageWidth = maxWidth;
        imageHeight = (imageWidth*image.getHeight()) // image.getWidth();
        }
        resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( 
                       image, imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
        }
        return resizedImage;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have apps that support multiple screen sizes also, and the link that krossovochkin supplied is the best one to use. However with my apps I used the following width sizes which seem to work fine and the resolutions are perfect for what I needed:

ldpi - 75px (120dpi resolution)
mdpi - 100px (160dpi resolution)
hdpi - 150px (240dpi resolution)
xhdpi - 200px (320dpi resolution)

But these all depend on what you are going to be displaying on the buttons
NB: Ensure that you scale your buttons DOWN not up!

Alternatively see this [device display](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html)

Comment: Your image sizes are in pixels, not in dp.

Comment: My bad, that's my graphic design background taking over, they are actually dp not px

Comment: No - an image size is always in X px by Y px at N dpi

Comment: in the drawable folder images have different size in pixels, but actually the same size in dips, so everything is ok: for ldpi 75px image, for mdpi 100px image and so on

Comment: ldpi might be 75 px @ 120 dpi, mdpi 100 px @ 160 dpi, and so on. When you reference the image **in your xml layout**, then you use the mdpi reference as a dp unit: 100 dp, in this case.

Comment: as per @DerGolem comment - Didn't explain myself very clearly in my answer

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing in two different languages... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You do this wrong. You cannot just put the sane image in all folders - you need to **scale** it correctly for each bucket. As solution you should i.e. design all your graphics in one target density in mind (i.e. `xhdpi`) and then scale it down to match bucket requirements. Since scale factor is known you can do this in many ways (also by using tools like: [9patch resizer](https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/), [FRED](http://blog.leocad.io/fred-android-drawable-resizing-tool/), [Drawable Resizer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219584) or others).

See this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article on developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this...

```
<Button  
android:id="@+id/button5"
android:layout_width="230dip"
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:background="@drawable/a"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create images of differents sizes and put them in its corresponding folders, `drawable-mdpi`,  `drawable-hdpi` etc. You should not modify the values in your xml code. Check the article of [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html). You need to start at a scale, for example `xxxhdpi`, and from there scale down your images for densities mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.

Comment: Upscaling is rather bad idea. Also it is waste of time because framework will do that for you. Proper approach is to downscale to avoid artefacts and pixelation

Comment: I agree, never upscale as you lose image quality, always downscale (start off with the largest and scale down to smallest)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, @Android-converter, I do not know if its a good practice, but it is the way Android shows in his docs: `So where do you begin when designing for multiple screens? One approach is to work in the base standard (normal size and MDPI) and scale it up or down for the other buckets. Another approach is to start with the device with the largest screen size, and then scale down and figure out the UI compromises you'll need to make on smaller screens.`.

Comment: The first approach makes no sense. And the fact it is in official docs makes this "advice" even worse.

Comment: I change it to downscale, but, developer.android.com is not the official docs?

Comment: @algui91 - I would always scale down rather than scale up, I find that unless you create vectors from scratch then scaling up will reduce image quality. It also makes it easier IMO because you are then only scaling one way not scaling up then having to scale down

Comment: @Android-converter, Yes, it makes sense to scale down rather than up, I only wantted to point out that he need to use the folders `drawable-*` for his question. I've change it to scale down.